# Retrieving and set field values in Content types

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-type, field

I want to set values on some content types fields with code. The values is stored in some fields in another Content type. I have looked around to fond some tutorials but can not find any.
The problem is as follows:
I have two content types: scorecard and golf_course. The scorecard have a reference field to the title field of the golf_course. Depending on the selection I want to transfer some values (par and index on the holes) from the golf_course to the scorecard.   This means that I want to load the fields  from the golf_course of choice and set this values to the corresponding fields in the scorecard (I need this to be able to do calculations).
Hope some one would be kind enough to share some hints to me.
I have some knowledge about php but need some training especially on this entity concept that is used in Drupal. If someone have some links or books to suggest I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After studding Drupal a bit deeper using Buildamodule.com and other sources I now know that the question was wrong formulated and I have also take another angel to the issue.
So here I am just now:
I store some data in sql-tables and I use the  form api to build a form to get the starting values from the user. Some of this values they can pick from select fields supported from the sql-table. In the submit-function (after validating) I build a new node of the content type scorecard using Entity API. For this part I using the method described in http://drupal.org/node/1388922  .
I set values to some of the field and then saving the node with

```
 entity_save('node', $entity)
```

This works fine.
The final thing I want to do is to load the created and saved node and view the node to the user as the final result of the submit function.
I have tried to put this at the end of the submit function but it did not worked:

```
 $node=node_load(the nid of the saved node);
 node_view($node);
```

After some more search I found this:

```
  cache_clear_all();
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/nid ';
  return;
```

That I think solved it.